# Отключить перезапуск программ

Tags: windows, windows-10, автозагрузка

В Windows 10 добавили автоматический запуск программ, которые не были закрыты до того, как пользователь решил выключить компьютер ([пруф](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-fall-creators-update/a35b3f3d-f750-48c3-ae0f-1d0ccd097486)). Ненавижу эту фичу, от неё сплошной вред. Как-то можно отключить???

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/25/block-reopening-of-programs-on-windows-10-start/